# What is the meaning of these words?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, terminology, phrase-meaning

group of six rough **frame buildings** was bisected by a narrow dirt street; there was a scattering of tents beyond the buildings on either side. The wagon passed first on its left a loosely erected tent of army **drab** with **rolled-up sides**, **which held from the roof flap a flat board** crudely lettered in red, JOE LONG, **BARBAR**. On the opposite side of the road was a **low building**, almost square, windowless, with a flap of canvas for a door; across **the bare front boards** of this building were the more carefully executed letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame buildings: The structures are mostly bare, wood frames, no stone, concrete, etc.
Army drab: a dull, grayish-green color common in the U.S. Army
Rolled up sides: likely canvas, rolled up in warm weather
Roof flap: overhanging board
Flat board: a board hanging vertically from the roof flap
Barbar: A misspelled "barber," written on the flat board. Cuts hair.
Low building: a one or two-story building
Bare front boards: though the sides are likely covered in canvas, there are a couple of bare boards covering the front of the structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.excuse me, i have another question. My main problem is with this sentence " which held on the roof flap a flat board " , can we say it means something like this: a broad attached to the doily or ridge of tent upright?

Comment: @So GH Yes, a board attached to the overhang of the canvas roof of the tent.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much.